# Sign in anonymously always fails

Tags: javascript, html

I call Anonymous function that calls firebase.auth().signInAnonymously(); when the button is clicked. But when onAuthStateChanged is activated, the user is always null. I checked the firebase and signInAnonymously is enabled. Please help

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.0.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.0.0/firebase-database.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.0.0/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
    <script src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
<script>
        var firebaseConfig = {
                key
            };
            firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
</script>

<script>
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
        if (user) {
            // User is signed in.
            var isAnonymous = user.isAnonymous;
            var uid = user.uid;
            alert('signed in')
        } else {
            alert('not signed in!')
        }
        // ...
        });

function Anonymous(){
            firebase.auth().signInAnonymously();
        }
</script>
```